# How to use RSS in android aplication to show stockexchange status?

Tags: java, android, rss-reader

I am new in android, I want to build an application in android which will show the stock exchange status using rss-reader.

Please guide me how to implement it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recently created an Android library that handles parsing for you. Its simple to use and can be customized to fit your needs. Look at the readme for a tutorial on how to implement it.

https://github.com/ShirwaM/Simplistic-RSS